# Traefik rewrite URI while keeping query string

Tags: traefik

In Traefik 1.7 I would like to rewrite:

https://example.com/?uuid=1234

to

https://example.com/foo/bar/?uuid=1234

I'm using something like this in a docker-compose file

```yaml
labels:
 - traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://example.com/$$
 - traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://example.com/foo/bar/
```

Which only works without the query string. How do I get it to work with a query string?